# HTML/CSS - img out of its li container

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I'm trying to create a menu and I've spent a few hours without finding a solution. I don't understand why my img (logo.png) don't stay in its li container. I've added borders to try to understand the problem. Found several same problems online but it didn't solve mine...
Thank you for your help!

EDIT: here is the img logo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIMR5.png)

output:
[image: menu]

Here is how it should look like (less space on top and bottom of elements)
[good menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fIU8.png)

EDIT2: still stuck: no matter the way (flex, block, grid...) I can't get the logo img to be vertically centered in its li. Here is my last try with block and vertical align:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpydsbjw/1/

### DEMO

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}

.container { /* règles générale de mise en forme des containers */
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  
}


/*---------------------MENU------------------------------- */

.menu > div.container { /* couleur fond menu */
    background-color: #DD5555; 
}



.ElementsMenu{      /* la liste du menu */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap:2rem;
    margin-left: 140px; 
    margin-right: 600px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }


.ElementsMenu > li{ /* mise en forme des éléments du menu */

    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    line-height: 52px;
    list-style:none; /* supprime les puces */
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      
}


.logo > img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid rgb(172, 178, 15);
}



a{ /* Mise en forme de la police du menu */
    text-decoration : none; /* supprimer soulignage du texte menu */
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="ElementsMenu">
                        <li class="logo"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/20/d4q5.png"  alt="Logo"></li>
                        <li><a href="">A propos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">L'équipe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Try clear fix hack.

Comment: Can you please provide an example with a logo image that actually matches the dimensions of the image you used in your screenshot.

Comment: I checked the example and it looks fine, I don't know why in your image you saw your logo unaligned

Comment: What browser did you use please Ali ?

Comment: I am using chrom

Comment: Me too, v. 102.0.5005.63. Strange...

Comment: You're confused why your `<img>`, inside of an `<li class="logo">` element, is being pushed down, when you have this in your CSS: `.logo > img{ margin: 0 auto; margin-top:1.8rem; }`? I think you may have - inexplicably - created your own problem. Learn to use your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I've spent so much time and tried so many different ways that I may have mess up my code. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Use Display "flex" property instead of "block".

check this out.

```
.ElementsMenu > li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 52px;
    list-style: none;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried this and the other problem I have then is that I can't find a way to align vertically the logo with the other items. 

https://zupimages.net/up/22/22/ktlj.png

How can I vertically center the <img> in the <li> Any idea ?

Comment: copy the above CSS codes and replace them all ".ElementsMenu > li". align-items of flex properly will help you to align the child's top(start), middle(center), and bottom(end). I already fixed the issue as you described. If you are still confused then take a look at a tutorial about CSS flex properly and how it works.

Comment: Already did change the code with yours, and spent a few hours yesterday on CSS flex tutorial and I coulnd't find a way to do it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***grid*** instead of ***flex*** I think it's easier to work with
please try this, I think it will solve the problem

```
  .ElementsMenu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, max-content);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  .ElementsMenu > li {
    line-height: 52px;
    list-style: none; /* supprime les puces */
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I also already tried this and, as for previous solution with 'flex', I then have a problem to vertically center the logo with the other items. How to do that ?

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for you but look at the screenshot of my browser with style at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thanks. I tried with your code and, same problem, I then can't vertically align the img in the li: https://zupimages.net/up/22/22/d6dz.png